# Htaccess rewrite - ignore rule for specific url structure

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

#
# Externally redirect direct client requests for index page filepaths to “/” URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/\ ]+/)*index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# Externally redirect direct client requests to remove file extensions from obsolete inbound links
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/\ ]+/)*([^.\ ]+\.)+(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.(php|html?)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
#

# Externally redirect non-canonical hostname requests to canonical hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.mydomain\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
#

# Internally rewrite URLs requested with no filetype to php scripts
# unless the requested URL resolves to an existing directory or file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

It works perfectly (for those that are wondering what it does, it forces www domain, removed .html/.php extensions and automagically redirects urls with extensions to no-extension url.)

Now the good stuff:

I created a dynamic page at:

```
www.mydomain.com/opinion?name=namehere
```

I would like this url to be rewritten and force to:

```
www.mydomain.com/opinion-namehere
```

I tried adding this to the above htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^opinion-([A-Za-z])$ /opinion.php?name=$1
```

But that just gives me a "The requested URL /opinion-namehere.php was not found on this server." which makes sense because it is redirecting that url to a PHP by my original code, which does not exist.

Is there anyway I can make this work? Maybe ignore the rule for that specific url structure (/opinion.php?name)?

Thanks tons!

Francisco

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^opinion-([A-Za-z]+)$ /opinion.php?name=$1 [L]
```

above

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
```

**Clear your browser's cache before trying the above.**